# Differentiate EndDate(.CSV file)with today's date and send email if it's expire in 30days

Tags: bash

I have .csv file with the details Name,StartDate,EndDate. After read values from .csv file do compare with today's date and send an email if it's expire in x days. After read values from .csv unable to take values for condition. Can you please help..

file.csv:

```
Name: certificates, StartDate: Thu Dec 17 19:00:00 EST 2020, EndDate: Wed Dec 22 18:59:59 EST 2021
```

```
$ cat sample.sh
echo "=======Name, StartDate, EndDate Details============"
 
while IFS=, read -r Name StartDate EndDate;
do
    if [ -z "$EndDate" ]; then
        echo "$Validity details not exists"
    else
        echo "Name: $Name; StartDate: $StartDate; EndDate: $EndDate"
    fi  
done < file.csv

echo "=======$Name, StartDate, EndDate========"
```

I'm getting below output.. Not printing output after while loop closed.

```
$ sh sample.sh

=======Name, StartDate, EndDate Details============
Name: Name; StartDate: StartDate; EndDate: EndDate
Name:  sslcertificates; StartDate: Thu Dec 17 19:00:00 EST 2020; EndDate: Wed Dec 22 18:59:59 EST 2022
=======, , ========
```

Expected Output: I want to compare EndDate(.CSV file)with today's date and send email if it's expire in 30days

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the input you use. Make sure you copy&paste the code to the question. The output `=======, , ========` does not match `echo "=======$Name, StartDate, EndDate========"`. I would expect output like `=======, StartDate, EndDate========`

Comment: What does "expire in 30 days" mean to you? That `EndDate - TodayDate` < 30 ?

Comment: It is a very well documented fact that variable values won't remain outside a read loop. Is that your problem?

Comment: Yes QuartzCristal, If EndDate -TodayDate < 30 need to send an email.

Comment: You should include the `text-processing` tags on your questions to attract the attention of more people interested in text processing tools such as awk, sed, etc.

Comment: Having said that - it's impossible for the script you show to produce the output you say it does (see [the first comment from @Bodo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/710428/differentiate-enddate-csv-filewith-todays-date-and-send-email-if-its-expire#comment1345180_710428)) and I highly doubt your input file `file.csv` really looks like you show with values like `StartDate: Thu Dec 17 19:00:00 EST 2020` instead of just the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use variables inside the read loop. It is a known (and well documented) fact that variable values read will lose their values outside the loop.

And you need to do the arithmetic of `EndDate - Today` in seconds.

Assuming you have GNU date, you can do:

```bash
$ cat sample.sh
echo "=======Name, StartDate, EndDate Details============"

TodayDateSec="$(date +'%s')"
 
while IFS=, read -r Name StartDate EndDate;
do
    if [ -z "$EndDate" ]; then
        echo "$Validity details not exists"
    else
        echo "Name: $Name; StartDate: $StartDate; EndDate: $EndDate"
        EndDateSec="$(date -d "$EndDate" +'%s')";
        DiffDays="$(( (EndDateSec - TodayDateSec)/86400 ))"
        if [[ "$DiffDays" -lt 30 ]]; then
              echo "Email needs to be sent"
        fi
    fi  
done < file.csv

echo "=======$Name, $StartDate, $EndDate========"
```

The values of read variables will still be empty after the loop, but the need to send an email has already been tested (and printed).

Comment: Hi QuartzCrista, Thanks for response
Showing date is wrong and DiffDays showing -19193, I'm not sure why output printing 2 times. Could you please help..
Output below:
Name: Name; StartDate: StartDate; EndDate: EndDate
test.sh: date: command not found
 Name: Name  StartDate StartDate: StartDate EndDate: EndDate, -19193
Name:  sslcertificates; StartDate: Thu Dec 17 19:00:00 EST 2020; EndDate: Wed Dec 22 18:59:59 EST 2021
test.sh: date: command not found
 Name:  sslcertificate  StartDate StartDate: Thu Dec 17 19:00:00 EST 2020 EndDate: Wed Dec 22 18:59:59 EST 2021, -19193

Comment: From `date: command not found` it seems that you are missing the command `date`, then, install it !.

Comment: Hi QuartzCrista, "date" command exists and working but getting error, I tried command with /bin/date and date as shown below (in while loop)but no luck.

                date=`/bin/date`
                EndDateSec="$(/bin/date -d "$EndDate" +'%s')";
                DiffDays="$(( ( EndDateSec - TodayDateSec )/86400 ))"

/bin/date: invalid date ‘EndDate’
***********-19194************
Certificate is going to expire in -19194. Please take required action
/bin/date: invalid date ‘Thu Aug 18 18:59:59 EST 2022’
script: